# classes have been opened collapse in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I use andriod studio,I will open several classes.Once the classes I open are more and more,the bar will collapse.Just like the picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec2ab.png)

The result I want is that,the classes have been opened don't collapse,all the classes will dissplay in the bar.Who can do me a favor?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Just uncheck the red one, when you want to configure something, type in the search bar on the left-top